# MemSQL - Memory Leak

Tags: singlestore

I have a cluster of 5 MemSQL Nodes and 2 Aggregators running this on 300 GB of memory.

Our size of row stores is fairly small less than 20 GB to be precise. The problem that we are facing is after few days the memsql memory is at 100% and at that time the application has to be restarted.

Is there a way to force the memory clean up

Comment: Jump onto our public stack channel: http://chat.memsql.com/

Comment: Please provide more details about your workload. Do you have to restart MemSQL or your application?